# Hibernate @Formula building query incorrectly

Tags: hibernate, annotations, formula

I'm adding a formula to a field:

```
@Formula(value = "(select count(*) from approvalGroup as a where a.isAccounting=true)")
```

But the query is failing because Hibernate is trying to make 'true' a field on my object.
Exception:

```
[ERROR] Unknown column 'approvalgr0_.true' in 'where clause'
```

How can I tell Hibernate this is a constant value and not something it needs to retrieve from the entity object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Josh, Hibernate formulas are applied as native SQL (not HQL) and probably SQL dialect of your DBMS don't have *true* keyword. Try changing code as follows

```
@Formula(value = "(select count(*) from approvalGroup as a where a.isAccounting)")
```

Also use DB column names instead of using names of persistent entity properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just discovered that @Formula(value = "(select count(*) from approvalGroup as a where a.isAccounting=1)") works as well.  Also, I am using sql and db column names.

Comment: But don't you think "=1" is redundant?

Comment: @Trader001 Not if the column type allows other values as well.